# OpenFire Content Filter using REGEX

Tags: regex, openfire, profanity

Hi i am currently implementing the following regex to prevent user submitting contents which contains profanity as describe within the regex

```
(?i)(pecan|tie|shirt|hole|ontology|meme|pelagic|cock|duck|slot|anjing lo|Banting|Chiba|Screw|Screwing|fat|where|mother|peer|per|sock|socker|locker|ans|rect|anal|pickpocket|joker|muck)\b
```

I would like to improve the regex so it also filter out credit card number (master, visa, jcb, amex and so on)

i have the regex for each card namely:

```
 ^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$ (Visa)
^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$ (Master)
^3[47][0-9]{13}$ (Amex)
^3(?:0[0-5]|[68][0-9])[0-9]{11}$ (Diners)
^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$ (Discover)
^(?:2131|1800|35\d{3})\d{11}$ (JCB)
```

However when i combine these credit card amex along with the profanity filter like this

(?i)(pecan|tie|shirt|hole|ontology|meme|pelagic|cock|duck|slot|anjing lo|Banting|Chiba|Screw|Screwing|fat|where|mother|peer|per|sock|socker|locker|ans|rect|anal|pickpocket|joker|muck)\b (?i)^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$\b (?i)^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$\b it will ignore the profanity filter.

Can anyone points me to the right direction?

Comment: Aside from the fact that [smut filters never work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html), why would you worry about someone entering profanities into a credit card number field?

Comment: both are policy requirements. Sharing sensitive information such as TFN (Tax File Number), CCs are prohibitted in the system that i am building.

Comment: Oh, and by the way, thanks for an interesting list of swearwords, many of which I didn't know before. Where are they commonly used? (Just so I can prepare well for my next holiday there) :)

Comment: those are Melayu words commonly used in countries such as Singapore, Malaysia, Indonesia/Bali.

Comment: I'm a Singaporean and even I don't know any of the words in the list @TimPietzcker, but that may be because I'm not Malay...

Answer (score 0):

Filtering profanity is a great example when NOT to use regex!... Anyone who wants to swear can easily get around your filter by typing "0" instead of "o", or inserting a "." in the middle of a word, or hundreds of other workarounds. There are much better alternatives out there, if you'd like to do some [research](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordfilter). Anyway, ignoring that...

Firstly, do you really need to do this in a single regex pattern?! Your code would look much more readable and be more easily maintainable if you split this into multiple lines of code.

But if you really insist on doing it this way, your pattern is looking for a swear word, followed by a Visa number, followed by a Master number. You have not implemented any "OR" condition here.

Comment: As far as i know it is the limitation of OpenFire plugin where i can only put one-regex-to-rule-them-all within the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the stupidest policy requirement I've ever seen. Your filter will miss a lot of profanities, and will trigger on non-profanities; see [Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem).

Then, your credit card regexes already exclude all possible swearwords because they allow only digits, out of which it is going to be difficult to construct a swearword.

But if your boss insists, make him happy with

```
(?i)^(?!.*(pecun|tai|shit|asshole|kontol|memek|pelacur|cock|dick|slut|anjing lo|bangsat|cibay|fuck|fucking|faggot|whore|motherfucker|peler|pler|suck|sucker|fucker|anus|rectum|anal|cocksucker|sucker|suck)\b)4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$
```

Comment: Yup, i am aware about the scunthorpe problem. At somepoint in the future i might as well create a custom openfire plugin as a way around this problem. I tested yours sadly it escapes the profanity list. Perhaps OpenFire treat regex list differently. I am not sure about this.

Comment: Ah, you had two credit card checks in a row. Hadn't seen that.

Comment: When i test the regex here http://regexp-tester.mediacix.de/exp/regex/ it does not catch any of the profanity. Let me try using OR between profanity and CC check

Comment: What do you mean "catch"? It should fail to match if there is a swearword there, shouldn't it?

Comment: I mean it will not filter any of the profanity word as specified within the regex. Give it a try at the link i posted above. As shown here http://imgur.com/LUDX30o

Comment: Define "filter". The regex is designed not to match when such a word is encountered. And it has succeeded.